# Default OperatorColor ParameterColor black-on-black in Powershell console

Tags: windows-10, powershell, powershell-core

For some reason, my PowerShell console renders these two elements black-on-black, making the terminal very hard to use.

Running

```
Get-PSReadLineOption
```

Gives me:

```
CommandColor                           : "`e[93m"
CommentColor                           : "`e[32m"
ContinuationPromptColor                : "`e[37m"
DefaultTokenColor                      : "`e[37m"
EmphasisColor                          : "`e[96m"
ErrorColor                             : "`e[91m"
KeywordColor                           : "`e[92m"
MemberColor                            : "`e[97m"
NumberColor                            : "`e[97m"
OperatorColor                          : "`e[90m"
ParameterColor                         : "`e[90m"
SelectionColor                         : "`e[90;47m"
StringColor                            : "`e[36m"
TypeColor                              : "`e[37m"
VariableColor                          : "`e[92m"
```

[image]

This wasn't always the case. But on my machine it has made Black the PSCore 6 background color, yet it seems to assume the old PS blue background color.

How do I fix this once and for all on my machine?

Comment: As the background color (and the whole colortable) is either inherited from the console ***or*** from any shortcut used to start the current invocation of powershell/pwsh there can't IMO be once and for all solution. The colortable could also be modified with i.e. [windows-console-colortool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/11/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/). BTW here my powershell.core has `"`e[90m"` set for both OperatorColor and ParameterColor on black background.

Comment: Has here too, but it renders as black on this machine instead of grey (as on my other machine)...